# Sorting a array of string by 3rd character of string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Below is a list of names.

Jacob,
Ethan,
William,
Logan,
Jacob,
Andrew,
Alexander,
Jackson,
Chase,
Noah,
Michael,
Andrew,
Alexandre

Q - Sort names by 3rd character (ascending order). e.g Noah or Chase will be at the top

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, we will not do your entire homework for you, only help you with it. Show us your code and focus on a specific problem you're having. Tell us what you already understood, where you are struggling, and [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What do you mean by 3rd character?

Comment: Could this be what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17260579/7680338

Comment: usort($data, fn($a, $b) => strcmp($a[2], $b[2]));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [spaceship operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) in tandem with [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) might be of help here.

We are applying the custom `cmp()` function to `$names` and comparing the third character (zero indexed) from each string.

```
<?php

$names = ['Jacob', 'Ethan', 'William', 'Logan', 'Jacob', 'Andrew', 'Alexander', 'Jackson', 'Chase', 'Noah', 'Michael', 'Andrew', 'Alexandre'];

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return $a{2} <=> $b{2}; // Spaceship operator
}

usort($names, "cmp");

echo '<pre>';
print_r($names);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Result:**
[image: Result]

Please note that the spaceship operator requires PHP >= 7